# $X\subsetneqq Y$ but $X^\star=Y^\star$

Tags: functional-analysis

Are there $X,Y$ real Banach spaces, such that $X\subsetneqq Y$ (strictly contained) and $X^\star=Y^\star$, where $\star$ denotes the topological dual?

This property is not true for Hilbert spaces, nor even for $L^p$ spaces, so I was thinking to try some function space: continuous functions or bounded...

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Just a random thought: if you take $\ell_2$ and $A \subset \ell_2$ which is defined as the subset made of all sequences with first coordinate zero, they are both isometric to $\ell_2$, so their duals are isometric, which is how I interpreted $X^\star = Y^\star$.

Comment: @Second: I don't think this is what the OP wanted; if $X \subset Y$, then $Y^*$ is naturally mapped to $X^*$ (a linear form on $Y$ induces a linear form on $X$). I believe the question is whether this map is an isomorphism?

Comment: Do you mean that the transpose of the inclusion map is a topological isomorphism? Or that there exists a topological isomorphism whatsoever?

Comment: What do you mean by $X^*=Y^*$ exactly? That the duals are isomorphic (via a continuous isomorphism)? Isometric?

Comment: Yes @julien , there is an isomorphism between then.

Comment: Should we understand your question like Second and I did, or like nik? Please clarify, thanks.

Comment: @julien , I am a little confused here. If $X\subset Y$, can I identify $Y^\star$ with a subspace of $X^\star$?

Comment: If $X\subseteq Y$, you get a canonical surjection $Y^*\longrightarrow X^*$ by restriction. Hahn-Banach show it is surjective. Then you can mod out by the nullspace, which is the orthogonal of $X$ in $Y^*$. That's isometric, then.

Comment: Well ok @julien. For example, we have that $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, but $(\mathbb{R}^N)^\star=\mathbb{R}^N$, so $\mathbb{R}^2\subset \mathbb{R}$. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think there is a confusion between the notions of dual and orthogonal here.

Comment: @julien, you mean that in the answers down there, they used the notion of orthogonality, insted fo duality?

Comment: No, they use the notion of duality. Me too, actually. But you seem to think that $X\subseteq Y$ implies canonically that $Y^*\subseteq X^*$. This is false. What the two answers show is that the canonical surjection $Y^*\longrightarrow X^*$ is not injective when $X$ is a proper closed subspace of $Y$.

Comment: Hmm ok @julien, now things clarified for me. But why do you deleted your answer?

Comment: Because I was not sure what you were asking. If it answers your question, I'll undelete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you are asking whether $X^*$ and $Y^*$ can be isomorphic (there exists a (bi)continuous isomorphism between them) when $X$ is a proper closed subspace of a Banach space $Y$.

Yes, this can happen. Even with Hilbert spaces. I would say especially with Hilbert spaces. It suffices that $X$ and $Y$ be isomorphic. And that's necessary if they are reflexive, like in the Hilbert case.

E.g.

a) $X=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\subsetneq \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})=Y$ has $X^*\simeq Y^*\simeq \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ isometrically.

b) More generally, for an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$ and any proper closed infinite dimensional subspace $K\subsetneq H$, we have $K^*\simeq H^*\simeq \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ isometrically.

c) In $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$, we have $c_0\subsetneq c$ and $c_0^*\simeq c^*\simeq \ell^1$ isometrically where $c$ (resp. $c_0$) is the subspace of sequences that converge (resp. to $0$).

d) And here is a somehow silly example: take $X=C([0,1])\subsetneq C([0,2]=Y$ with the obvious embedding which extends a function continuously by a constant on $[1,2]$. Then $X^*\simeq Y^*$ isometrically as follows from Riesz representation theorem. Or much easier, from the fact $X$ and $Y$ are obviously isometric.

Comment: I think that my comment after my question, had mislead the answers of the other guys, nonetheless I haven't say anything specific about the canonical surjection.

Comment: Of course, none of these isometric isomorphisms of dual spaces is in any sense canonical. // The most interesting instance is in c) where $c_0$ and $c$ are *not* isometrically isomorphic (in the examples in a), b) and d) it is easy to see that $X$ and $Y$ are isometrically isomorphic). Worse, still: it is known that $\ell^1$ has a continuum of non-isomorphic pre-duals.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the note. But you scared me, I thought I had said something wrong...

Comment: No, no worries, you didn't -- although I tend to read an  equality sign to mean at least that there is a canonical isomorphism if it isn't literal equality, which is probably what triggered the first sentence of my comment.

Comment: @Martin Oh, I see. You're right. I pasted the OP's question...I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

Choose a point $p$ in $Y$ outside $X$ and construct a linear functinal $f$ on $X+\mathbb R p$ which vanishes on $X$ whereas $f(p)=1$.  By the Hahn-Banach theorem, $f$ extends to a functional on $Y$.  Clearly therefore the duals of $X$ and $Y$ are never the same.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice nik already answered this.

Comment: The unstated assumption that $X$ is closed in $Y$ is of course used here.